# SQL - Ignore the first character of a field's text

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Let me lay out what some of these fields look like before I explain what I need to do...

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      T1.CustID      |   T2.CustID      |   T2.ExtCustID   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1234       |       1234       |         A1234    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So I need to build a where statement that basically ignores the first letter in the ExtCustID and tries to find the same ID in T1.CustID

T1 and T2 are joined via CustID (inner-join) but I can't figure the where statement out...

I've tried stuff like `where T1.CustID like (right(T2.ExtCustID and where T1.CustID like (substring(T2.ExtCustID`   but I'm not sure I can use RIGHT/SubString/TRIM to do this...  Can anyone point me in the right direction/give me an example?

NOTE - I'm using Oracle!

Comment: Sorry about that ^   - I updated it

Comment: And I learned something about Oracle. Kinda nice that the SUBSTR function doesn't require the number of characters parameter, unlike MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

where T1.CustId=substr(T2.ExtCustId,2)

Comment: Thank you.  I hope this and the other answers help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
RIGHT(T2.ExtCustID, LEN(T2.ExtCustID) -1 )
```

This returns the x rightmost characters of ExtCustID, where x is the LEN (number of characters) of ExtCustID, minus 1.

Comment: It'd be nice if a brief explaination is added about how this solves OP's problem

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that I'm using Oracle...  This is why my original right statements did not work.  I'll edit the OP now

Answer (score 0):

SQLCliff ended up giving me the stepping stones to the solution.  For some reason I wasn't really thinking about the length...

I also didn't update the OP and say that I'm using Oracle...  All my fault not yours!

But here's the solution I fixed up -

```
where not(t1.CustID like substr(t2.customer_external.external_customer_code,length(t2.customer_external.external_customer_code)- 5))
```

Comment: @access_granted gave you the much, much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use below statement 
Right(fieldname, len(fieldname)-1)